# Dependencies discovery in other layer's module using Ninject.MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

Main Question: How do I discover dependency configured with Ninject.MVC3 in other layers?

Background:

I am using Ninject.MVC3 in one of my ASP.NET MVC4 project.

I have used ServiceLocator before but new to Ninject. The setting Ninject up and configuring is so simple with new enhancements.

The new Ninject.MVC3 Nuget package, add a "`NinjectWebCommon`" class into your web project's App_Start folder and that is where we configure all the dependencies. This class is static and does not expose anything outside except Start and Stop static method that returns void.

In order to use it, you can configure a dependency in its "`RegisterServices`" method e.g.

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    { 
        kernel.Bind<IDataContext>().To<MyDataContext>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "name=MyDataContext");

        kernel.Bind<IRoleService>()
        .To<RoleService>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("dbContext", context => context.Kernel.Get<IDataContext>());
    }
```

In the business layer we can use any of the configured services e.g.

```
public class RoleService : IRoleService
{
    private readonly IDataContext _dbContext;

    public RoleService(IDataContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

Now suppose we want to add a new dependency say ILogger to this class `RoleService`. Current how i have to do it is like this:

```
public class RoleService : IRoleService
{
    private readonly IDataContext _dbContext;
    private ILogger _logger;

    public RoleService(IDataContext dbContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

I am wondering is this the only (or ideal or standard) way to allow a module to discover dependencies?

With `ServiceLocator` I would have done this:

```
    public class RoleService : IRoleService
    {
        private readonly IDataContext _dbContext;
        private readonly Lazy<ILogger> _logger;        

        public RoleService(IDataContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _logger = Locator.Current.GetInstanceLazy<ILogger>();
        }
    }
```

I tried looking around but mostly found constructor based injection for Ninject.

The problem with constructor based approach is, obviously as you add more dependencies the constructor parameter list grows. I know, SRP coming into picture :) but you know <3 dependencies are normal. Each class needs DbContext, Each class needs a logger, and if you happen to have a separate auditing feature than that's third.

What's the deal with property based injection. I just tried, I added a property like so:

```
    [Inject]
    public IRoleWrapper RoleWrapper { get; set; }
```

in the RoleService class which exist in business layer. The property is not initialized and set to null. What should I do to make Ninject initialize it, please mind the ninject initialization is done in MVC web project.

To summarize my questions are:

1. What's better approach out of these two Constructor Vs Property injection w.r.t. Ninject MVC3 package?
2. Is there an alternative way I can discover dependency in my business layer classes like I can do using ServiceLocator?
3. How is the property injection supposed to work in above case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I prefer constructor cause it gives me better overview and I used to it
2) You should create the StandardKernel objcet in the bottom of the layers and every component including the UI project should use that object
3) You have to instantiate through the ninject. Ninject will fill the contructor parameters, and search the type for property injections.
Example:

```
  public interface IBusinessClass {
    int DoWork();
  }

  public class BusinessClass : IBusinessClass
  {
    public int DoWork()
    {
      return 10;
    }
  }
  public interface IBusinessClass2
  {
    int DoWork2();
  }

  public class BusinessClass2 : IBusinessClass2
  {
    public int DoWork2()
    {
      return 20;
    }
  }
  public class Consumer
  {
    public IBusinessClass2 BusinessClass2 { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IBusinessClass BusinessClass { get; set; }

    public Consumer(IBusinessClass2 businessClass2)
    {
      BusinessClass2 = businessClass2;
    }
  }
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
      kernel.Bind<IBusinessClass>()
            .To<BusinessClass>();
      kernel.Bind<IBusinessClass2>()
            .To<BusinessClass2>();

      Consumer c = kernel.Get<Consumer>();
      Console.WriteLine(c.BusinessClass.DoWork());
      Console.WriteLine(c.BusinessClass2.DoWork2());
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

UPDATE:
About the MVC module. It's generate NinjectWebCommon.cs for you when add to your project.
It has a `Create()` method inside:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
    kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

    RegisterServices(kernel);
    return kernel;
}
```

Modify this method n to use a new Kernel but your kernel from the base library:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = // kernel from base library
    kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
    kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

    RegisterServices(kernel);
    return kernel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Considering we have multi layer arch, we should create a separate library project in which we will add Ninject and configure it with dependencies. In web project during pre-start or start up, we shall initialize this new library. Did I get it right? Going to try it now...

Comment: You can use webactivator in the other libraries: [assembly:WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(className),"parameterlessStaticMethodOfThatClass")]

Comment: Created a separate library project, installed Ninject into it. Configured one dependency. Web project has a reference to this assembly, on debug Start method is getting called. However now controller ctor that has a parameter is not getting called. "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." I place [Inject] in controller ctor but same problem. I guess i have to do something extra to make Ninject being share between project, will explore. Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks @Péter once again. That's sound appealing solution. Will implement it today and accept your answer. Thanks.